# .NET: HttpClient mocking it with my Interface IHttpClient, but there is an internal object that is NULL and it is sealed

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have created my own IHttpClient so I am able to mock HttpClient using moq. Works pretty well but there is an internal object called DetaultRequestHeaders which has a property called Authorization.

I am setting this in my constructor or my class that accepts in an injected IHttpClient, of course at runtime everything works as expected. But using Unit Tests I get an error saying

```
    Object reference not set to instance....
```

This is due to the fact that the DefaultRequestHeaders is null.

Now after inverstigating this further it appears that it is of type

```
    HttpRequestHeaders
```

but it's a sealed class so I can't even do this:

```
    .Setup(x => x.DefaultRequestHeaders).Returns(return new HttpRequestHeaders())
```

This is the interface definition

```
    HttpRequestHeaders DefaultRequestHeaders { get; }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your syntax on the `Returns` method call appears incorrect. The fact that `HttpRequestHeaders` is a sealed class shouldn't have any bearing on whether you can return an instance of it from a stubbed method call. Try changing that call to `Returns(new HttpRequestHeaders());` or `Returns(() => new HttpRequestHeaders());`.

If that doesn't work (or the concrete implementation of `HttpRequestHeaders` is somehow unsuitable for your needs), you might need to try a framework that can mock sealed classes, perhaps Moles or JustMock.

Comment: "The type 'System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders' has no constructors defined". Its constructors are all internal.

Answer (score 17):

Just inject the concrete HttpClient and mock the underlying HttpMessageHandler...

http://geekswithblogs.net/abhi/archive/2013/11/20/unit-tests-for-httpclient-using-httpmessagehandler.aspx

> You can unit test a class that uses HttpClient by giving that
> HttpClient a mock HttpMessageHandler. This way, you can capture the
> request and prevent it from actually going over the wire.
>
> Here is an example using Moq. HttpClient depends on
> HttpMessageHandler’s SendAsync() method, so give SendAsync() a stub
> implementation and use Moq’s Callback() to capture arguments.
>
> ```
> var handler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
>
> handler.Protected()
>
>     .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
>
>     .Returns(Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
>
>     {
>
>         return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
>
>     }))
>
>     .Callback<HttpRequestMessage, CancellationToken>((r, c) =>
>
>     {
>
>         Assert.AreEqual(HttpMethod.Get, r.Method);
>
>     });
>
>  
>
> using (var client = new HttpClient(handler.Object))
>
> {
>
>     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://www.google.com");
>
>     var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
>
>     Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
>
> }
> ```

Comment: This is a good answer. HttpClient doesn't do a whole lot besides delegate to its message handler, so the message handler is a good place to inject your mock.

Comment: Per [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), `Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`

Answer (score 4):

`HttpRequestHeaders` has only internal constructor.
But you can do it by creating `HttpRequestMesssage` object:

```
var message = new HttpRequestMessage();
.Setup(x => x.DefaultRequestHeaders).Returns(message.Headers);
```